# visual studio 2010 very slow to load and build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have installed Visual studio 2012 on my system and after that my system is damn slow. Even Visual studio 2010 ( which was installed before) is very very slow. It takes 15 minutes to open. 5 minutes to buld a simple hello word program. I recently installed only Vs 2012 and Windows 7 SP1.

Please tell me how I can speed up VS 2010 ( not 2012). It has telerik controls added as well. I am ready to remove it if necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running low on disk space?

Comment: Something is seriously broken on your machine if it takes 15 minutes to start VS.  There is no hint whatsoever in your question that would allow a guess at the cause.  You'll have to do the leg-work to find clues.

Answer (score 0):

something tells me it might just be a slow pc?

EDIT: so as not to just leave a troll post, i recently got VS 2012 and it hasnt affected my load/build or compile times at all

Comment: I am using Core I 5 and it was fine before these installations.

Comment: how much RAM though? i5 wont mean much if your only running about 2GB ram and have other stuff open at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If Vs 2012  Try this: Remove all the "UNUSED" MS Access or other data files in the App_Data folder - including any that are in sub folders. If you have old versions in App_Data or in any sub folders then Visual Studio will have to open all of them even if your website does not use them.  In my case it took 2 - 3 minutes to open the website and even longer to close.  I had 50 or so backups and test databases I kept in various folders just a archives. I just moved them to another folder in my website.  Wow - Visual Studio now opens in a few seconds.